# handling json response asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Check the code

```javascript
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var parsedUrl = require('url').parse(req.url);
    var pathname = parsedUrl.pathname;
    pathname = pathname.replace('/get/','');

    GPSData.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err, data, data.length); 
        res.writeHead(200, {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        });
        console.log('hello');
         res.end(data);
    });

});
```

How to get json data from db and show in response? If I move res.end('some-json') out of GPSData.find() then I can see my page in browser but how to show data from db in response?

How to handle all this asynchronously?

Comment: This shouldn't be async unless you really want to render the page and the JSON separately (over websockets or whatever). Is the problem that the page doesn't render if you keep res.end inside the callback?

Comment: Yes if res.end is inside the callback, page does not render

Comment: And 'hello' gets output to console? What does data look like at that point?

Comment: Yes it has correct data at point where I am saying Hello to console. But response has already finished so browser is displaying "This web page is not available"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found that I need to stringify my data before sending back response

```
var body = JSON.stringify(data);
res.end(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

If browser is displaying "This web page is not available" then either you should get some error messages in console, or you are simply missing `server.listen(<port_number>);` at the end.